# dict.values() doesn't provide all the values in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

The dict.values() doesn't provide all the values which are retrieved inside a for loop. I use a for loop to retrieve values from a text file.

```
    test = {}

    with open(input_file, "r") as test:
        for line in test:
           value = line.split()[5]
           value = int(value)
           test[value] = value
           print (value)

   test_list = test.values()
   print (str(test_list))
```

The value and test_value doesn't contain equal number of data

The output is as followed:

*From printing "value":*

```
88
53
28
28
24
16
16
12
12
11
8
8
8
8
6
6
6
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
2
2
2
2
2
```

*From printing test_list:*

```
list values:dict_values([16, 24, 2, 4, 53, 8, 88, 12, 6, 11, 28])
```

Is there any way to include the duplicate values too, to the list?

Comment: Did you realize that you're using the name `test` for two different things? I hope that's a transcription error from your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) keys cannot contain duplicates. When you are doing `test[value] = value` the old value at the key `value` is overwritten. Thus you get a limited set of values only.

A sample test can be

```
>>> {1:10}
{1: 10}
>>> {1:10,1:20}
{1: 20}
```

Here you can see, the duplicate key is overwritten with the new value

**POST COMMENT EDIT**

As you said you want a list of values, you can have a statement `l = []` at the start and have `l.append(value)` at the place where you have `test[value] = value`

Comment: Is there a way to get the values including the duplicates into a list?

Comment: But when I do it I get an error **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'**

Comment: yes I did `output = [] output.append(int(value)) print ("list values:" + str(output))` I did it like this but I get the error I mentioned

Comment: I tried removing as you said. Works fine ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
test[value] = value
```

Doesn't add a new value to `test` if it's a duplicate, it simply overwrites the old value. So any duplicates get removed. The `values()` call is truly returning everything that remains in the dict.

Comment: How can I get the values including the duplicates. As I need all the values into the dictionary

Comment: @user3703782 it seems like you need a `list` instead of a `dict`. Maybe you could edit the question to tell us more of what you're trying to accomplish overall?

Answer (score 1):

This is because python dictionaries cannot have duplicate values. Everytime you run `test[value] = value`, it replaces an existing value or adds it if it's not in the dictionary yet.

For example:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['a'] = 'b'
>>> d
{'a': 'b'}

>>> d['a'] = 'c'
>>> d
{'a': 'c'}
```

I'd suggest making this into a list, like:

```
output = []

with open(input_file, "r") as test:
    for line in test:
       value = line.split()[5]
       value = int(value)
       output.append(value)
       print (value)

print (str(output))
```

Comment: But I get an error **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'**

Comment: Did you set the first line to `output = []`?

Comment: yes I did `output = [] output.append(int(value)) print ("list values:" + str(output))`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'` means that `output` is still a dict. Somewhere you are setting it to a dictionary. You aren't doing `with open(input_file, "r") as output` right? That should still be `test`.

Comment: That's true there was another parameter with `page_name = {}`, I changed it to `page_name = []` everything is fine now. Thanks